# Programmatically add an invoice to Dynamics AX 2009

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, ax

I'm am pretty new to Dynamics AX 2009 and since I haven't really found the way to solve what I'm doing I decided to ask here.

I have a requirement to post(?) an invoice through X++.

I already found this [HOWTO: Facturación selectiva de líneas en Dynamics AX](http://www.jaestevan.com/howto-facturacion-selectiva-de-lineas-en-dynamics-ax) and even though it's in Spanish I think you will get the idea.

Here is the code I modified from the link:

```
static void JAEE_PurchFormLetter(Args _args)
{
    Num                 _invoiceNum;    // Núm. factura
    TransDate           _invoiceDate;   // Fecha factura

    MyPurchFormLetter     purchFormLetter =       PurchFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::Invoice);
    PurchParmUpdate     purchParmUpdate;
    PurchParmTable      purchParmTable;
    PurchParmLine       purchParmLine;

    TradeLineRefId      tableRefId;
    PurchTable          purchTable;
    PurchLine           purchLine;
    ;

    ttsbegin;

    _invoiceNum = 'Facbyjob';
    _invoiceDate = str2date('14-01-2013', 123);

    purchTable = PurchTable::find('00000019_062'); // Primer pedido
    // Inizializar purchFormLetter con el primer pedido
    purchFormLetter.parmCallerTable(purchTable);
    purchFormLetter.callInitParmPurchTable(purchTable);
    purchFormLetter.proforma(false);                                // Proforma: NO     (Registrar: SI)
    purchFormLetter.enableUpdateNowField(true);                     // Actualizar ahora: SI
    purchFormLetter.printFormLetter(false);                         // Imprimir: NO
    purchFormLetter.transDate(_invoiceDate);                        // Fecha de factura

    // Inizializar purchParmUpdate con el primer pedido
    purchParmUpdate.clear();
    purchParmUpdate.initValue();
    purchParmUpdate.ParmId              = purchFormLetter.parmId();
    purchParmUpdate.SumBy               = AccountOrder::Account;    // Agrupar por cliente
    purchParmUpdate.SumNum              = _invoiceNum;              // Núm. Factura
    purchParmUpdate.SpecQty             = PurchUpdate::All;         // Actualizar: Todo
    purchParmUpdate.DocumentStatus      = DocumentStatus::Invoice;  // Tipo documento: Factura
    purchParmUpdate.Proforma            = NoYes::No;                // Proforma: NO
    purchParmUpdate.SumIncludePending   = NoYes::No;                // Incluir pendiente: NO
    if (purchParmUpdate.validateWrite())
        purchParmUpdate.insert();
    else
        throw Exception::Error;

    purchFormLetter.purchParmUpdate(purchParmUpdate);
    purchFormLetter.parmParmTableNum(purchParmUpdate.SumNum);

    // Tabla temporal, se crea un registro de cabecera del primer pedido (sólo uno)
    purchParmTable.clear();
    purchParmTable.TableRefId = FormLetter::getTableRef();
    purchFormLetter.createParmTable(purchParmTable, purchTable);
    if (purchParmTable.validateWrite())
        purchParmTable.insert();
    else
        throw Exception::Error;

    tableRefId  = purchParmTable.TableRefId;

    // BEGIN - LINEAS
    //       - Repetir para cada línea que se quiera facturar y para cada una y 
    //       - asignar las variabies purchTable y purchLine según proceda
    purchParmLine.clear();
    purchParmLine.initValue();

    // Ajustar cantidades según necesidades

    // Catnidades de compra
    [purchParmLine.ReceiveNow,
     purchParmLine.RemainBefore,
     purchParmLine.RemainAfter] = purchFormLetter.qtyPurch(purchLine, naReal());

    // Cantidades de inventario
    [purchParmLine.InventNow,
     purchParmLine.RemainBeforeInvent,
     purchParmLine.RemainAfterInvent] = purchFormLetter.qtyInvent(purchLine, naReal());

    if (purchParmLine.ReceiveNow)
    {
        purchParmLine.ParmId = purchParmUpdate.ParmId;
        purchParmLine.initFromPurchLine(purchLine);
        purchParmLine.setLineAmount();
        purchParmLine.TableRefId = tableRefId;

        if (purchParmLine.validateWrite())
            purchParmLine.insert();
        else
            throw Exception::Error;
    }
    // END - LINEAS

    // Registrar!
    purchFormLetter.reArrangeNow(false); // No organizar
    purchFormLetter.run();

    ttscommit;
}
```

My question is in this line:  `purchFormLetter.callInitParmPurchTable(purchTable);`.

Why should `initParmPurchTable()` be called from within a derived class of PurchFormLetter?

And also, how to accomplish this? I tried declaring my own class `MyPurchFormLetter` which extends `PurchFormLetter`, adding the `callInitParmPurchTable()` method but compiler tells me that the object does not have the method when I try to run the code.

It reads:

```
Error al ejecutar código: Object objeto no tiene el método 'callInitParmPurchTable'.
```

EDIT:

What I have done is add the method *into* the class, in such a way that `callInitParmPurchTable()` *is* part of the object. But I am leaving the question open since I don't think this is the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the following:

It is correct to make a class that inherits from `PurchFormLetter` and implement there the method `callInitParmPurchTable()` which obviously is the one that executes `initParmPurchTable()`.

Most likely the one part that I had been missing was to compile `MyPurchFormLetter` so that the compiler could tell the method existed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you modified `PurchFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::Invoice);` to return a MyPurchFormLetter?

Also look into the "compile forward" feature

Comment: Good suggestion. Try right-clicking on PurchFormLetter in the AOT and clicking Compile Forward.

Comment: @davidLawson @sshaheen, Thank you for your suggestions, but what gets returned is a `PurchFormLetter_Invoice` object, and by judging the code I feel like it should remain that way.

Comment: @ackzell, callInitParmPurchTable exists on the class MyPurchFormLetter, not PurchFormLetter_Invoice. You are returning a  PurchFormLetter_Invoice from PurchFormLetter::construct and so attempting to call a method that does not exist on that PurchFormLetter_Invoice object

Comment: Thanks again @DavidLawson, I figured that and I have changed my approach as I explained after editing my question.